# Why is preg_replace removing umlauts?

Tags: codeigniter, preg-replace, special-characters

I am trying to create an preg_replace for my search form, but it keeps replacing umlauts too...

```
Code:
    $zoekwoord = $this->input->get('q', TRUE);
    $zoekwoord = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]u/s', '', $zoekwoord);

Any idea how to keep special chars? (like ö)
```

Comment: Try `'/[^\w %[\].()%&-]+/u'`

Comment: Yeah, thanks! It worked :D

Comment: Glad it worked, I added the answer and explanations below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the pattern that removes any char but an ASCII letter, digit, `_` and some special chars.

You need to replace the `[A-Za-z0-9_]` with `\w` and make it Unicode aware with the `/u` modifier.

Use

```
'/[^\w %[\].()%&-]+/u'
```

Note that only `]` needs to be escaped inside this character class. `/s` modifier is redundant, and I believe you made a typo adding `u` to the end of the pattern.